# QML image widget visibility

Tags: qt, qml

I have a window with a QML image in it that needs to flash, so I use a Timer and toggle the visible flag every 500ms. The image has its size, max size, min size and preferred size set to 24. However, the widget next to it in the RowLayout moves backwards and forwards when the visibility changes. How can I make the icon flash without invalidating the layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `opacity: 0` instead of `visible: false`.

Or, alternatively, do something like this:

```
RowLayout {
    // ...
    Item {
        width: 24
        height: 24
        Image {
            anchors.fill: parent
            // ...
        }
    }
```

... and just toggle the `visible` property of the **Image**, like you've been doing.